# How to go to next input by tapping return key on an iPhone/iPad with Ionic2?

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using Ionic Cordova to build an iPhone app. I have a login screen username input and password input plus a submit button. I cannot make to focus on password input after typing the username and tap "return".

My login.html looks like this:

```
<ion-list >
     <ion-item>
<div id="loginlogo"></div>
     </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked>Username</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" name="usernameInput"  (keyup.enter)="focusAndGo()" [(ngModel)]="usernameInput"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked>Password</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="password" id="passwordInput"  name="passwordInput" [(ngModel)]="passwordInput"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
     <ion-item><button (click)="logincontrol()" ion-button color="light" block>Login</button></ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

and my login.ts look like this:

```
@ViewChild('passwordInput') nameInput;
  focusAndGo()
  {
    var input = document.getElementById('passwordInput');
    input.focus();
    this.nameInput.setFocus();
    //this.nameInput.nativeElement.focus();
    //this.nameInput.nativeElement.setFocus();
    //this.passwordInput.focus();
    //alert(event.keyCode );
    //if( event.keyCode ==13)
    //{
    //this.passwordInput.focus;
    //}       
  }
```

I tried everything that is commented above. I cannot get cursor to move to next input.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should prevent default behaviour before setting focus,

send $event to your function

```
<ion-input type="text" name="usernameInput"  (keyup)="focusAndGo($event)" [(ngModel)]="usernameInput"></ion-input>
```

and use preventDefault() before setting focus

```
focusAndGo(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var input = document.getElementById('passwordInput');
    input.focus();     
}
```

Comment: Thank you NTP. I will try and I will let you know the result.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help.

Comment: Hi NTP. Sorry I was away. I just tested when I tapped return the cursor didn't focused on password input. I put ```àlert('test');``` at the end of the function just to test if it is called. It is definitely  pops an alert up when I tap return key but it is not focusing on password field. Do you have any other suggestion or and idea why it is not working? Thanks heaps for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**Update** for a better aproach: [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53690973/change-behaviour-of-enter-key-in-a-phone-angular-5/53691367#53691367)
(I updated the post after received an upvote, but I think the correct answer is the indicate in the link)

it's a old post but a posibility is make a directive like

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[next-tab]',
})
export class NextTabDirective{

  @Input('next-tab') nextControl: any;

  @HostListener("keydown.enter", ["$event"])
  onEnter(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (this.nextControl.focus)
    {
      this.nextControl.focus();
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

then you can use a form like

```
<form [formGroup]="dataForm" (submit)="submit(dataForm)">
   <input        formControlName="data1" [next-tab]="data2">
   <input #data2 formControlName="data2" [next-tab]="data3">
   <input #data3 formControlName="data3">
   <button type="submit">Click</button>
</form>
```