# How to set focus when you press enter on ngx-select-ex?

Tags: angular

I am using the [ngx-select-ex](https://github.com/optimistex/ngx-select-ex) component.

At [my github](https://github.com/abelardolg/helloworld-select) I have added two instances of that component to test them: src/app/test/app.component.html

I would like to gain the focus of the second component when I press enter on the first one.

If the console is opened it will show 4 elements with 'form-control' class because each `ngx-select-ex` component contains 2 subcomponents with this style.

Inside the app.component.ts I capture the 'keydown' event:

```
@HostListener('component:keydown', ['$event'])
  keyEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log($('.form-control'));
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
   // do something stuff
    } else {
      console.log("else");
    }
  }
```

How could I gain the focus of the second ngx-select-ex when I press the 'Enter' key on the first one?

Best regards.

Comment: Can't you use the method (close) ?

Comment: Method 'close' doesn't set the focus on the next element

Comment: see my answer using (close)

Answer (score 1):

@Abelardo, supouse that you have

```
<ngx-select ...(close)="nextInput.focus()">
<input #nextInput type="text">
```

See how we referred to the input using a template reference variable (#nextInput), and how using this in the "close" method. I haven't ngx, but must be work

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen this comment until now. :/

Inside the 'app.component.html' file I have included two instances of 'app-mytest' (which includes an only 'ngx-select-ex' component).

An instance of 'app-mytest' has an ID="select1" and another one has ID="select2". 

I would like to gain the focus of the second instance of 'ngx-select-ex' (select2) when I press enter on the first instance (select1).

You can download my repo. :)

Comment: And not work? I supouse you can use a template reference variable https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var- with anything

Comment: It doesn't work. 
Yes, I use a template reference variable in each instance of app-mytest:
<app-mytest
  #select1
  [myId]="'select1'"
...
<app-mytest
  #select2
  [myId]="'select2'"
...

Also, I would like the second component gains the focus not only when the first one closes its list of items.
Imagine that you wouldn't like to show the list but you press the enter key...

...

Comment: In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47951591/how-to-go-to-next-input-by-tapping-return-key-on-an-iphone-ipad-with-ionic2/49845232#49845232 I make a directive to make the ENTER focus the next field (I used for a cordova project, but the idea is the same)

Comment: It 'kind of' works for me with (close)="nextInput.focus()", but for some reason the page jumps. Actually, before I added this (close) handler, the page was jumping to the top, so this is much better, I just wish I could get it to not move after closing the ngx-select. Note: this works perfectly in Firefox, but has the jump in IE 11 only, but I have to support IE.

Answer (score 0):

In you parent component: you should use [@ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) to capture both components. (Alternative: use [ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren)

so for instance:

```
<select #selectA .... >

@ViewChild('selectA') selectA: ElementRef;
```

When you handle the select events, you can check for the Enter:

```
keyEvent(event) {
  if(event.keyCode == 13) { // enter

  }
```

and when you handle the enter press event, you can set the wanted element's focus like this:
`selectA.nativeElement.focus()`

**Update:** see my [working example with simple imputs here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wg2rkt?file=app/app.component.ts).

html:

```
<p>input1: </p>
<input #input1 (keydown)="handleKeydown($event, 1)"/> 
<br/>
<p>Input2: </p>
<input #input2 (keydown)="handleKeydown($event, 2)"/>
```

ts:

```
 @ViewChild('input1') input1: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('input2') input2: ElementRef;

  handleKeydown(event: KeyboardEvent, id) {
    console.log("Event:", event)
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      console.log("Enter pressed, focusing...")
      if (id === 1) {
        this.input2.nativeElement.focus();
      }
      if (id === 2) {
        this.input1.nativeElement.focus();
      }
    }
```

Comment: I tagged both components with '#select1" and "#select2" respectively.
Inside the app.component.ts, I created two references to these components via @ViewChild and I captured the event.keyCode to manage the enter key but...it didn't work. I got this message:  Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined.

Comment: I have created a basic stackblitz example, and updated my answer with it. Please check it, it does exaclty what you whist to do but with native html inputs, not select components.

Comment: also, your error message indicates, that your object what you are calling .focus() is not defined: maybe you are referencing a wrong object, or it did not match any element in your DOM by the id. ( #someID must be referenced without the hashmark: @Input('someID'), etc.)

Comment: Your stackblitz example didn't work for this component. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I think this component would have to be referenced as 'NgxSelectComponent' rather than 'ElementRef'.

Comment: Sorry, but without the exact code, can't help you more than that. Could you please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your problem?

Comment: The code is at my Github: https://github.com/abelardolg/helloworld-select

Comment: your repo appears to be broken on a clean install. (ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(5,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jquery'.)

Comment: It was fixed. I have forgotten to include "jquery": "^3.3.1" inside the package.json. Thanks for your report. :)