# Change behaviour of enter key in a phone - Angular 5

Tags: html, angular, input

I am working with `input`s but I am not really sure about how is the configuration of the navigation done (I guess that it are predefined behaviours).

I am not in the last `input` the enter key goes to the next one. This one is working as I want. 
[image]

Nevertheless, when I am on the last `input`, when I press enter, it automatically clicks on the next `button`. 
[image]

This is what I am trying to avoid. Is there any way to change this behaviour? Just to close the keyboard or to click on another `button`?

I have tried with `keyup.enter` and it pseudo works. It calls to the method but also clicks on the next `button`

**HTML**

```
<input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          id="validationCustomSurname"
          placeholder="e.g. Lopez"
          required
          (keyup.enter)="onNavigate(1, 'forward')"
          [(ngModel)]="values.store.surname"
          name="surname"
        />
```

This method should work on a phone, so I guess that `keydown` is not an option since `$event.code` does not give me any code in the phone.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53519041/3769965

Answer (score 4):

Some time ago I make a directive [see stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ab94st?file=src%2Fapp%2Fenter-tab.directive.ts) that you apply in a div (or in a form) in the way

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (submit)="submit(myForm)" enter-tab>
    Each input or button add a reference variable #nextTab like
    <input name="input1" formControlName="input1" #nextTab/>
    <button type="button" #nextTab/>
</form>
```

The directive use ContentChildren to add a keydown.enter to all the components that have #nextTab to focus to the next control

```
export class EnterTabDirective {
  @ContentChildren("nextTab") controls: QueryList<any>
  nextTab

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) {
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.controls.changes.subscribe(controls => {
      this.createKeydownEnter(controls);
    })
    if (this.controls.length) {
      this.createKeydownEnter(this.controls);
    }
  }
  private createKeydownEnter(querycontrols) {
    querycontrols.forEach(c => {
      this.renderer.listen(c.nativeElement, 'keydown.enter', (event) => {
        if (this.controls.last != c) {
          let controls = querycontrols.toArray();
          let index = controls.findIndex(d => d == c);
          if (index >= 0) {
            let nextControl = controls.find((n, i) => n && !n.nativeElement.attributes.disabled && i > index)
            if (nextControl) {
              nextControl.nativeElement.focus();
              event.preventDefault();
            }
          }
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

Comment: In case someone needs this to work with angular material, just add `descendants: true` to `ContentChildren`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple approach, with just a few lines of code:

First, in your `Template` when you dynamically create your `Input` elements: 1. populate the `tabIndex` attribute with a unique number, 2. populate a super-simple custom "Tag" Directive with the same unique number as the `tabIndex`, and 3. set up a Keydown "Enter" event listener:

`Template:`

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let row in data">
   <input tabindex ="{{row[tabCol]}}" [appTag]="{{row[tabCol]}}" (keydown.enter)="onEnter($event)" . . . />
</ng-container>
```

In your `component`, your super-simple event-listener `onEnter()`:

```
@ViewChildren(TagDirective) ipt!: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  onEnter(e: Event) {
    this.ipt["_results"][(<HTMLInputElement>e.target).tabIndex%(+this.ipt["_results"].length-1)+1].el.nativeElement.focus();
  }
```

Note: The modulus (%) operation is just to make sure that if you're at the last `Input`, you'll get cycled back to the first input.

Super-simple, bare-minimum "Tag" `Directive`

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appTag]'
})
export class TagDirective {
  @Input('appTag') id: number;

  constructor(public el: ElementRef) { }

}
```

There's probably even a way to get rid of the "Tag" `Directive altogether and make it even more simple, but I haven't had time to figure out how to do that yet . . .