# Enter key press behaves like a Tab in Angular

Tags: angular, enter, tabindex

I have an Angular 2+ form group and each form field has tabIndex.

How do I change focus to the next form field on each Enter key press (similar to pressing tab)?

JavaScript Reference - [Enter key press behaves like a Tab in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009808/enter-key-press-behaves-like-a-tab-in-javascript)

Comment: I know my answer went unnoticed :(, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53690973/change-behaviour-of-enter-key-in-a-phone-angular-5/53691038

Comment: @Eliseo, I have tried the code and doesn't work in my case I'm generating the controls dynamically.

Comment: if you put #nextTab I don't know because can not work. Check -writing console.log(querycontrols.length) in the function createKeydownEnter to check if the directive is taking account your constrols

Comment: I tried debugging, querycontrols.length always comes 0. Even I tried with AfterViewChecked.

Comment: see the new https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m8jtwp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html. See how I reffered to the controls in a FormArray, like `[formControl]="lineas.at(i).get('prop1')"` I try use FormArrayName, GroupName and so and don't work, but using formControl it's OK. If not work, tell more data about how generate the controls dinamically

Comment: @Eliseo, I have used GroupName, FormArrayName and FormControl. so it is not working for me.

Comment: has you see the new stackblitz? There are two examples, one using FormArray, another one dinamic Form, I hope this can help you

Comment: @Eliseo, Your implementation is right. seems something is not working in my case. I will put my code in stackblitz so you can have a look. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 5):

I would do this with a simple directive and a much simpler service.

**tab.directive.ts**

```js
import { Directive, Input, ElementRef, HostListener, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TabService } from './tab.service';
type IKNOWISNUMBER = any;
type IKNOWISSTRING = any;

@Directive({
  selector: '[tabIndex]'
})
export class TabDirective implements OnInit {

  private _index: number;
  get index(): IKNOWISNUMBER{
    return this._index;
  }
  @Input('tabIndex')
  set index(i: IKNOWISSTRING){
    this._index = parseInt(i);
  }

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onInput(e: any) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
      this.tabService.selectedInput.next(this.index + 1)
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private tabService: TabService) { 
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.tabService.selectedInput.subscribe((i) => {
      if (i === this.index){
        this.el.nativeElement.focus();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**tab.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
 
@Injectable()
export class TabService {
  selectedInput: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>(1);
}
```

I've created a little [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uqksnn?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab.service.ts) to show how it works.

P.S.
Remember to provide the tab.service inside every component with a form, cause you need a specific instance for each form.

Comment: if you want take a look to my comment at top

Comment: @Eliseo I really like it, but I have a question. The ViewChildren already orders the controls by tabIndex or you have to order them programmatically when the directive is created?

Comment: ViewChildren order the elemens by position in the DOOM (Almost I beleive in this). If you want to change, is possible: First you pass to array using toArray, order the array and use reset with the array ordered.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple approach, with just a few lines of code (which I also posted here:[Change behavior of Enter key . . .](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53690973/change-behaviour-of-enter-key-in-a-phone-angular-5/58329789#58329789)  ):

First, in your `Template` when you dynamically create your `Input` elements: 1. populate the `tabIndex` attribute with a unique number, 2. populate a super-simple custom "Tag" Directive with the same unique number as the `tabIndex`, and 3. set up a Keydown "Enter" event listener:

`Template:`

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let row in data">
   <input tabindex ="{{row[tabCol]}}" [appTag]="{{row[tabCol]}}" (keydown.enter)="onEnter($event)" . . . />
</ng-container>
```

In your `component`, your super-simple event-listener `onEnter()`:

```
@ViewChildren(TagDirective) ipt!: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  onEnter(e: Event) {
    this.ipt["_results"][(<HTMLInputElement>e.target).tabIndex%(+this.ipt["_results"].length-1)+1].el.nativeElement.focus();
  }
```

Note: The modulus (%) operation is just to make sure that if you're at the last `Input`, you'll get cycled back to the first input.

Super-simple, bare-minimum "Tag" `Directive`

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appTag]'
})
export class TagDirective {
  @Input('appTag') id: number;

  constructor(public el: ElementRef) { }

}
```

There's probably even a way to get rid of the "Tag" `Directive altogether and make it even more simple, but I haven't had time to figure out how to do that yet . . .

Comment: It's generally not a great idea to set tabindex over 0 otherwise you have to keep up with it to make sure you don't have tabbing jump all around the page. Not that you can't use values greater than 0, it can just lead to unexpected and undesirable behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```js
export class InputNumberComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() model: number;
    @Input() tabIndex: number ;
    @Output()
    changedValue = new EventEmitter<number>();
    constructor() { }
    
    valueChanged(value): void {
        this.changedValue.emit(value);
    }
}
```

```html
  
  <input tabindex="{{tabIndex}}"  [(ngModel)]="model"  (change)="valueChanged(model)"/>
```

if use angular and make input component only use html "tabindex" in html

and define @input to .ts file get tabindex
@Input() tabIndex: number ;